# After adding "greeter-show-manual-login=true" I can't log in

Tags: lightdm

After I entered this command in terminal:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "greeter-show-manual-login=true" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'
```

and I reboot my PC I cannot login. After I select the os in GRUB it takes me to a black  screen and I can't do anything even though Ubuntu seems to run; everytime I turn off my computer via the power button the Ubuntu logo appear. I think it has got to do with lightdm. I have tried to run in safe graphics mode but nothing happen what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you

When you power on the computer, and ubuntu will load, try to press [Left Control] + [Left Alt] + [F1]
Then log in to the system via terminal, then go to the path /etc/lightgdm by command:

```
cd /etc/lightdm/
```

Then edit the file lightdm.conf with your editor like: nano or vi (nano is much more easier here). It will ask you for your password again

```
sudo nano lightdm.conf
```

And delete the whole line that you added

```
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

Then save it with keyboard command [Left Control] + [x], it will ask you "Save modified buffer" press key [y] and then it will ask "File Name to Write: lightdm.conf" just press [Enter]

Finally type

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Or use live cd, and then edit the file.

Comment: it worked so thank you very much but if i want to have a root acount and lightdm is causing me these problems how can i have a root account

Comment: In ubuntu 14.04 they moved and renamed that file. Go to "/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d" and there is a file named "50-ubuntu.conf" just add that line "greeter-show-manual-login=true" at the bottom of that file, and reboot system.

Comment: @xylo Uhhh..isn't that my answer below?

Comment: I'm on my android, your answer did not load so i did not read it. Sorry mate :)

Comment: @xylo its fine!

Comment: @Zorbacator "if i want to have a root acount and lightdm is causing me these problems how can i have a root account" Its not clear what you are asking here... Can you elaborate? If it is relevant to this question then post about this problem too here it self. Else make it a separate question...

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` doesn't exist in Ubuntu 14.04 ! I tried

```
locate /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

in my Ubuntu 14.04 and this is what I got :-

```
/etc/init/lightdm.conf
/usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
/var/lib/dpkg/info/lightdm.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/lightdm.config
```

Therefore it is clear that `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` doesn't exist. Well, I must add that it is not present *there*. Instead use `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf` . Its content is same as that of `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` as shown below:-

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
```

So remember:-

> The equivalent of `/etc/lighdm/lightdm.conf` in Ubuntu 14.04 is
>   `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf .`

Therefore you might edit your above command to :-

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "greeter-show-manual-login=true" >> /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf'
```

and it might work!